# What's the correct way to attach stovepipe to a wood stove?

Tags: woodstove

Look where the stovepipe sits on the flue collar of this woodstove. I don't see any way to secure the pipe to the stove. There is a gap because the stovepipe is not perfectly round.

At the other end of the stovepipe I will use 3 sheetmetal screws, but that won't work here.

The [manufacturer's manual](http://www.regency-fire.com/RegencyFireplaces/media/PDFs/Manuals-old/908-132.pdf) for the stove doesn't say anything.

How should I secure the stovepipe to the stove?

How should I seal the joint?

(click for full size)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see it before, but there were two small holes in the stove's flue collar. I put sheet metal screws through the holes in to the stovepipe, and things feel really solid.

Before inserting the pipe, I put some fire cement on the crimped end. After inserting, I spread some more around the joint, like caulking around a bathtub.

(click for full size)
[image]